# Mongodb Bulk find and remove is taking long time

Tags: mongodb, bulk-insert

I'm just making my hands dirty(handson) with MongoDB. First I did bulk insert of 1 million documents.

```
// Bulk insert query
var bulk = db.bulktest.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){bulk.insert({a:i});}
bulk.execute();
```

It took 10 seconds to insert all the document which is comparatively good. None of the documents were missed.

However, when it comes to bulk find and removal, the performance has drastically came down and is really bad as it is removing each document in the order of 10ms.

```
// find and removal bulk query
var bulk = db.bulktest.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){bulk.find({a:i}).remove();}
bulk.execute();
```

Has anyone done tweaking around bulk removal ?

I've only one option to drop the complete collection and I don't want to do this.

Comment: Have you added an index to `a`?

Comment: pch..!! just now tried with indexing, the removal was very fast. Less than 40 seconds. I totally forgot indexing. Thanks Derek

Comment: How about [db.collection.bulkWrite() with DeleteOne or DeleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#deleteone-and-deletemany)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't have anything to do with bulk operations. The `find` operation must read through the collection, which takes time on 1million documents.

Adding an index on `a` should improve the speed dramatically.